# JWT Authorization failing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, react-fullstack

So, I have this code. It used to work but due to some reason, it is failing now. I am preety sure that this part of the code is failing. The error in the frontend shows ***Logging in failed, please try again***. Everything else works file, I can fetch the existing user details from the database but still its failing.

```
  try{
    token = jwt.sign({userId: existingUser.id, email: existingUser.email},
       process.env.JWT_KEY,
       {expiresIn: '1h'});
    user.token = token;
  }catch(err){
    const error = new HttpError(
      'Logging in failed, please try again', 500
    );
    return next(error);
  }
```

Can anyone help me address this issue. Below is the full code for the file.

```
const { uuid } = require('uuidv4');
const {validationResult} = require('express-validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const fileUpload = require('../middleware/file-upload');

const User = require('../models/user');
const HttpError = require('../models/http-error');

const getUserById = async (req, res, next) =>{
  const userId = req.params.uid;

let user;
  try{
    user = await User.findById(userId);
  }catch(err){
    const error = new HttpError('Something went wrong, could not find a post', 500);
    return next(error);
  }

  if(!user){
    return next(new HttpError('Could not find a user for the provided id.', 404));
  }

  res.json({ user: user.toObject({getters: true}) });
};

const signup = async (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if(!errors.isEmpty()){

    return next(new HttpError('Invalid inputs passed, please check your data.', 422))
  }

  const {name, email, password} = req.body;

  let existingUser;
  try{
      existingUser = await User.findOne({email : email});
  }catch(err){
    const error = new HttpError(
      'Signup failed, please try again.', 500
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  if(existingUser){
    const error = new HttpError(
      'User exists already, please login instead.', 422
    );
    return next(error);
  }


  let hashedPassword;
  try{
    hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);
  }catch(err){
    const error = new HttpError('Could not create user, please try again', 500);
    return next(error);
  }


  const createdUser = new User({
    name,
    email,
    password: hashedPassword,
    posts: []
  });

  try{
    await createdUser.save();
  }catch(err){
    const error = new HttpError(
      'Signup failed, please try again', 500
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  let token;
  try{
    token = jwt.sign({userId: createdUser.id, email: createdUser.email},
       process.env.JWT_KEY,
       {expiresIn: '1h'});
  }catch(err){
    const error = new HttpError(
      'Signup failed, please try again', 500
    );
    return next(error);
  }


  res.status(201).json({userId: createdUser.id, email: createdUser.email, token: token});
};

const login = async (req, res, next) => {
  const {email, password} = req.body;

  let existingUser;
  try{
    console.log("Testing 1");
      existingUser = await User.findOne({email : email});
      console.log(existingUser);
  }catch(err){
    const error = new HttpError(
      'Logging in failed, please try again.', 500
    );

    return next(error);
  }

  if(!existingUser){
    const error = new HttpError(
      'Invalid credentials, could not log you in.',  403
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  let isValidPassword = false;
  try{
    isValidPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, existingUser.password);
  }catch(err){
    const error = new HttpError('Could not log you in, please check your credentials and try again.', 500);
    return next(error);
  }

  if(!isValidPassword){
    const error = new HttpError(
      'Invalid credentials, could not log you in.',  401
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  let token;
  try{
    token = jwt.sign({userId: existingUser.id, email: existingUser.email},
       process.env.JWT_KEY,
       {expiresIn: '1h'});
    user.token = token;
  }catch(err){
    const error = new HttpError(
      'Logging in failed, please try again', 500
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  res.json({
    userId: existingUser.id,
    email: existingUser.email,
    token: token
  });
};

exports.getUserById = getUserById;
exports.signup = signup;
exports.login = login;
```

Comment: console log the `err` from `catch(err)` and check what the error is ?

Comment: You have the same error message for "await User.findOne({email : email})". Try to console log the error and check what is it.

Answer (score 0):

This error is most likely a sync error.

use the promise chain.

example code

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // write code here.
    resolve(process);
})
.then((process) => {
    return process; 
})
.then((process) => {
    console.log(process);
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Handle in order your logic like the code above. This is a way to avoid sync errors.